# Why does one column seem to load first in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I have a Wordpress site that is doing something very bizarre. If you go to:

http://digitaldemo.net/joy/krippen-a-b-c/

When it loads, the main content div loads on the right hand side of the page
and then once the sidebar loads, THEN it gets pushed over to where it ought
to be.

It's only really noticable in Firefox, but I'd like to find out what is causing
it and fix the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create simplest possible example that would show the behaviour in http://jsfiddle.net/ and then post a link to the fiddle. I am almost sure that while doing that you will find the real cause and will be able to fix it.

Comment: that's just it - I can't duplicate it. All it is is one div floated left and one div floated right. Nothing unusual.

Comment: Here, I'll help you. This is your current source: http://jsfiddle.net/3ekCF/, still behaving as you described. The only problem is that is has A LOT of stuff that is really irrelevant. All the scripts and text and nesting, etc, etc. Try to tidy it up and see what happens.

Comment: I don't see quite what you've described, but I *do* see some very large text loading before the slightly smaller font that's being applied to it has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue! I added `position:relative` to the #content div and then added `position:absolute` and `left:30px` to the #content-left div. Voila!

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me!